# Typescript : Omit a property in an interface, when another property within the same interface equals a certain value from an enum

Tags: typescript

I would like to 'Omit' a property in an interface when another property within that same interface equals a certain value in an enum.
This however `DictionaryValue['type'] extends FieldType.ARRAY` always equals to false.

I don't want to make the property optional by default as this would possibly result to type errors in my code.

```
enum FieldType {
  STRING,
  NUMBER,
  ARRAY
}

interface DictionaryValue {
  type: FieldType,
  value: number
}

interface Dictionary<T extends string> {
  [key in T]: DictionaryValue['type'] extends FieldType.ARRAY ?
    Omit< DictionaryValue, 'value'> :
    DictionaryValue
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DictionaryValue['type']` will always be `FieldType`. A type is defined as is, not as to what might be in it when you declare a variable of the type.

You should consider having an union for `DictionaryValue` that contains the actual types you want for the values in the dictionary:

```
type DictionaryValue = {
    type: Exclude<FieldType, FieldType.ARRAY>,
    value: number
} | {
    type: FieldType.ARRAY
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAYglsANgEwCoE8AOwoG8CwAUFCVAMqoBKAkgHIDiANEaVLQKoCyAQgKKXNipAIKVKwgJpEAvkSIAXLDgAicAMby4AexABDAE7oAarsRgcAXjwtSi7AC4ovAB5qzyYAB54SNEsawCCgY2AB0ouISAHyCrABupuaO4BAARsD6MlAAPtZCJHbAjj7BSuFikjJyhIVQqhraeoaeqFDAzvKgyADOUN3y+nAgAOZRUFYE+VAA2gDWwOhQQ1CoALqO9Zo6BsaJwFWERGo6-VDIAIwb6ltN6J4A5PPo92MTNiRPjpOsrIXFQX4whFJLEfiQEmYijNVlAAPSwtr6fRaTJTWSEdHHECnZAAJiuDW2zUeCxe4zyrE+FLBUD+gV8IWAoQ4PH4oLBEKSUAADHDYZgtLN3lB0dIgA)